# VSCode keeps resetting my code folds whenever I sync changes

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-folding

Title says all, I like to keep my large files organized by collapsing many blocks of code. This is preserved even if I save my files or close and reopen VSC. However, when I sync and git pull, the affected files appear to lose their code folds. Is there any setting I can change where my folds can remain untouched even in this situation? It would save a lot of time!

Comment: I love it when things get closed as duplicates without saying what it's a duplicate of :') https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116767

Comment: I suggest you raise an issue ticket for this. If you do, please [edit] your question post to add a link to it for posterity.